# qt transfer a file from local to a samba shared

Tags: c++, qt, samba

I'm newly hired junior programmer, and I'm new in c++ world with no background in linux or networks. We are using gcc 4.7.3 and ubuntu 11.04. I need to know how to transfer file from my local desktop (example `/home/username/desktop`) to a samba (example `smb://192.168.0.54/folder` or `smb://username/folder`). First, I'm trying to do this (if I can access it)

```
  QDir dir("smb://192.168.0.54/htdocs/");
  if (!dir.exists()) {
      QMessageBox::about(NULL, "DIR", "dir does not exists");
  }
  else
      QMessageBox::about(NULL, "DIR", "dir exists");
```

and the result is "does not exist".  Can someone show me how to transfer files from my local desktop to an `smb://`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do that QFile just spports local files but you can mount it to a posix folder and access to that folder.

You can find a guide about how to mount a samba shared folder [here](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Mounting_samba_shares_from_a_unix_client)

Comment: thanks i will study this tomorrow on my work. i hope my boss will not terminate me for not able to do the task. this is my first job im fresh grad.